# How to make an HR element to be the same width of a text above it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like the width of this particular HR to be the same width of the "LARGER HEADER LIKE THIS" above it on any screen size. I have a default width for hr of 245px, but for this particular one I'd like to be as same as the width of the text above for any screen size

```css
hr {
  border-top: 0px solid blue !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0.5em !important;
  border-width: 6px !important;
  width: 245px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row text-center">
          <h1>HEADER 1</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="row text-center">
          <h1>LARGER HEADER LIKE THIS</h1>
          <hr>
       </div>
```

Comment: add style to that tag only. <hr style="width: 485px;">

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A better way would be to use the `hr` styles as a pseudo element of the text you want to apply it to. Here's an example.

```css
.hr {
  display: inline-block;
}
.hr:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-top: 6px solid blue;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h1>HEADER 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h1 class="hr">LARGER HEADER LIKE THIS</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

But you could also nest the `hr` in the `h1` and limit the size of the `h1`'s width to match the content by using `display: inline-block;` `float: left/right;` or `position: absolute`

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
hr {
  border-top: 0px solid blue !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0.5em !important;
  border-width: 6px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h1>HEADER 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h1>
      LARGER HEADER LIKE THIS
      <hr>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .heading {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    hr{
        border-bottom: 6px solid blue;
    }
</style>

<div class="row text-center">
  <span class="heading">
    <h1>LARGER HEADER LIKE THIS <hr></h1>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,
use border for the h1 element.
It's hard setting the width for the hr element to match h1 element, but we can tweak the h1 width to be equal to text size by using width = max-content.
For more information about width refer to this article, plus check compactibility list.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width?v=example

For maximum compatibility use javascript.
Use meta tag viewport to prevent zoom and have similar size.
use Line height to correctly position your text.

```
<html>
 <head>
     <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
 h1.example {
   border-bottom: 6px solid blue !important;
   padding: .5em;
   line-height: 50pt;
   border-width: 6px !important;
   width: max-content;

 }
.text-center{
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
 </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
       <div class="row text-center">
          <h1>HEADER 1</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="row text-center">
          <h1 class="exampe">LARGER HEADER LIKE THIS</h1>
          <hr>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class name to the hr you want to be different, and give it a width of 100%.

You could also try targeting it within the div structure, if you like. Something like:

```
    .container .row:nth-child(2) hr {
      width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: If his mark-up changes at all; this would be a disaster.

Comment: Well yeah, if you change your markup, obv your stylings would have to change.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply nesting a div around your `<h1>` and `<hr>` where you'd like them to share the same common widths; and you'll have that additional selector to do so.

*ie* `<div class="widthwrap"><h1>Heading</h1><hr>` and then:

```
.widthwrap hr { 
   width: $width;
   max-width: $max;
   min-width: $min;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Something like that; for a more clean, scale-able and maintainable solution. Rather then using global `hr` tag with a pseudo selector like `:after`

Or **better yet,** just give your specific unique `hr` tag a class to do what you'd like with.

*ie.* `<hr class="bigwidth">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use border-bottom on the header element and assign 'fit-content' to the width attribute.

However, please note that in your markup, you shouldn't have more than one < h1 > on a page for accessibility purposes. It's totally fine to style your < h2 > bigger than the < h1 > for the page, but a user using a screen reader and/or assistive technologies (AT) will have trouble navigating the page if it isn't properly structured in your markup.

Here's an example:

```css
h2 {
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-bottom: 6px solid blue;
  margin: auto;
}

hr {
  border-top: 0px solid blue !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0.5em !important;
  border-width: 6px !important;
  width: 245px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="play" class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>HEADER 1</h1>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <h2>LARGER HEADER LIKE THIS</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't do that. `h1` is a block element, and takes 100% width of its container, no matter the text size. There is no way for `hr` to know the text width, unless you calculate it in JavaScript and apply it there. Keep in mind that you'd have to keep re-calculating it on font size change, window size change, etc.

What you can do, however, is give the `h1` an `inline-block` display, then either:

1. apply a `text-decoration` of `underline`
2. add a pseudo element after the `h1`, and style that to achieve the `hr` aesthetic you desire.